# Missing declaration with default argument

Tags: swift, default-arguments

Is this code wrong, or is this a known issue?

```
final class Foo {
    //@inlinable @inline(_always)
    static func bar(_ first: String = "default", _ second: Int) {
        print(first,second)
    }
}

Foo.bar(2)
```

Will result: [image: Screenshot]

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. If you add an argument label to any of the two arguments like `static func bar(_ first: String = "default",second: Int)` or `static func bar(first: String = "default",_ second: Int) `, it compiles just fine. However, the compiler should still be able to infer that you want to call the default parameter with no argument labels, since the input arguments have different types. Btw the Swift naming convention is UpperCamelCase for types, so the class should be called `Foo`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor. Appreciate the tip. I noticed that too. However i won't be filing a bug report anytime soon. I need a simple, minimal workaround for this

Comment: workaround? I dont think there is one... its a bug... provide both params

Comment: You can change the function declaration as I've stated, other than that I don't see any workarounds without changing the function itself.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is it okay to leave this question open?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with your question and it can be beneficial for other people experiencing the same issue as well.

Comment: You can  try and ask on https://forums.swift.org/c/swift-users, perhaps this is an already known problem.

Comment: All done @MartinR thanks

Comment: @matt but shouldn't the compiler be able to infer which argument is missing based on their type? If it cannot, that might not be a bug, but rather a feature request, but still, this seems like something that _should_ be feasible.

Comment: It depends on what “should” means. You and I can imagine a language compiler that behaves that way, but I have zero expectation that the Swift compiler does.

Comment: @DávidPásztor even if both are Strings, it doesn't work

Comment: @Carpsen90 if both have the same type, it obviously won't work, how could the compiler infer which one you omitted then? My whole point was about the case when they have different types as in OP's implementation.

Comment: @DávidPásztor My point is: With this kind of declaration `func test (_ first: String = "world", _ second: String = "!") { print(first, second) }` You can't pass a single argument, and expect it to go to `second`. With multiple, **consecutive**, arguments that don't have external labels, values have to be provided to the first ones before the later ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say it is a bug more likely it is a feature. This code smells really bad codestyle...

- You don't specify the names for the parameter which can lead to really bad things and assigning `Int` to `String`... I wouldn't be surprised

Now I don't wanna "educate" you how to write nice code, but the example you posted above really is not. It is just not very intuitive to write functions without label, this is perfect example why we should be using labels... Writing functions as suggested by Swift community works just awesome...

```
    final class Foo {
    //@inlinable @inline(_always)
    static func bar(first: String = "default", second: Int) {
        print(first,second)
    }
}

Foo.bar(second: 2)
```

Why not just omit the underscores? :)

Answer (score 4):

I don’t find this surprising in the way that some of the comments do. Arguments must always be supplied in order. In the total absence of labels, the only valid way to do that is to supply the first argument or both. Supplying a single argument thus means you need to supply a string. The default value doesn’t change any of that.

The error message is unhelpful as usual, and other languages may behave differently, but that doesn’t constitute a bug. If there’s anything to complain of, it’s that the compiler should have warned against the original method declaration, as the default value for the first parameter is otiose.

Comment: As a newbie what would you suggest to put up an answer on a question like this?

Comment: Isn't "*total absence of labels*" a specific case of multiple consecutive arguments without labels?

Comment: Yup, this isn't a bug – [as Joe Groff says](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/1050123953316880384), arguments are lined up with parameters before type checking takes place.